# Combining environments in 2 packages (tkz-graph and tikzducks)?

Tags: tikz-pgf, tkz-graph, tikzducks

I made a graph using the tkz-graph package and want to use the tikzducks package to make vertices of the graph. (In particular, I want to replace the points at vertices of an arbitrary graph with colored ducks). Is this possible?

Here is my code:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
\renewcommand*{\VertexLineWidth}{2pt}
\GraphInit[vstyle=Welsh]
\Vertices[unit=3]{circle}{A,B,C,D,E,F,G}
\SetVertexNoLabel
\AddVertexColor{red}{B,F} \AddVertexColor{blue}{E,A}
\AddVertexColor{green}{C,G}\AddVertexColor{yellow}{D}
\Vertex[Node]{D}
\Edges(G,E,F,G,B,D,E,C,D,A,C,B,A)\Edges(B,E)
\end{tikzpicture}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Please always provide a fully compilable example that also includes the packages and libraries you use. This 1) helps to spot and resolve possible package conflicts and 2) helps others help you quicker, because they don't have to look for all the packages and libraries in order to compile your code.

Comment: By the way, it would probably a good idea if you could change the title of your questions so that they become distinguishable.

Comment: I did not see the other question first, but I am unsure whether this is a real duplicate since it uses `tkz-graph`. Of course, this package is also based on Ti*k*Z and one could go the same way as suggested in the answer to the other question.

Answer (score 1):

Sure, maybe like this:

```
\documentclass[border=10pt]{standalone} 
\usepackage{tkz-graph} 
\usetikzlibrary{ducks}

\newcommand*{\AddVertexDuckColor}[2]{%
    \begingroup
        \tikzset{VertexStyle/.append style = {duck = {duck/body=#1}}}
        \foreach \v in {#2} { \Vertex[Node, NoLabel] {\v} }
    \endgroup
}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \GraphInit[vstyle=Welsh]
    \tikzset{
        duck/.style={
            path picture={
                \pic[scale=0.25, xshift=-1cm, yshift=-1cm, #1] {duck};
            }
        },
        VertexStyle/.append style={
            draw=none,
            fill=none,
            minimum size=0.6cm,
            duck
        }
    }
    \Vertices[unit=3]{circle}{A,B,C,D,E,F,G}
    \SetVertexNoLabel
    \AddVertexDuckColor{red}{B,F} 
    \AddVertexDuckColor{blue}{E,A}
    \AddVertexDuckColor{green}{C,G} 
    \Vertex[Node]{D}
    \AddVertexDuckColor{yellow}{D}
    \Edges(G,E,F,G,B,D,E,C,D,A,C,B,A) 
    \Edges(B,E)
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]